# Node-http-proxy dynamic routetable?

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

im using following code for http-proxy:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {
    router: {
    'url1.com': '127.0.0.1:3000',
    'url2.com': '127.0.0.1:3001'
    }
};

httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

My question is, can i update the routetable dynamically? Without shuting down proxy server?

Thx for answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For everyone facing that problem, finally i got the solution out of the box. Its all possible, if u pass a string pointing to a file, instead of passing an object as arg. I'll give an example and it should be clear.

proxy.js:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var options   = { router: 'table.json' };

httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

As u see here, i pass table.json as router option. So look inside that file.

table.json:

```
{
   "router":
   {
      "domain1.com": "127.0.0.1:8080",
      "domain2.com": "127.0.0.1:8001"
   }
}
```

And thats the whole magic. node-http-proxy will monitor that file, and if you do any changes on it, it will update its routetable automatically.

Greetings

Comment: And that's how you get a working proxy server up and running in 5 minutes. I find NodeJS awesome. Light and simple.

Comment: Do they have a documentation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not using the ProxyTable.  I've documented [an alternative to http-proxy's ProxyTable called 'Switchboard'](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2011/11/30/idiot-ignore-switchboard/) that does what you want it to do.  You'll have to re-arrange some of the features to initialize the paths and backend targets properly, but it should be a straightforward operation, and the `backendTable` object is dynamically available at runtime.